# can't draw bezierPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code that I placed inside a UIViewController:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *trackPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [trackPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 30) controlPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    trackPath.lineWidth = 2;
    [trackPath fill];
    [trackPath stroke];
}
```

However, I am not seeing the path. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that drawRect is being called?

Comment: Is your stroke/context white?

Comment: actually drawRect is not getting called, not sure why

Comment: Views get drawn, not view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

UIViewController doesn't implement drawRect:. You need to override that method in a UIView subclass. Additionally, you're probably gonna want to set a color for the bezier path.